# Looking for quote from Maimonides on a widow wearing scarlet

Tags: rambam, clothing, sitting-shiva, yehuda

I was recently reading up on the account of Tamar and Judah (re' her widowhood and whether she was considered betrothed to Shelah), and I came across a quote from Maimonides in relation to her actions, describing how a widow will sit for a period and then 'arrays herself in scarlet'.

Now I can't find it. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Have you tried Googling ["arrays herself in scarlet"](https://www.google.com/search?q="arrays+herself+in+scarlet")?

Comment: @Tamir Evan 

:O  
I swear I did! 
But I didn't know you could use quotation marks for whole phrases like that, and I also included the word 'Maimonides', which apparently takes that result out completely! XD  
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [**Nachmanides**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides) (not Maimonides) [Ramban on Genesis 38:11:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.38.11.1?lang=bi):

טעם שבי אלמנה בית אביך, שתנהגי אלמנותיך שם עד יגדל שלה, רמז לה התאבלי ולבשי בגדי אבל, ואל תסוכי שמן, כאשה חגורת שק על בעל נעוריה, עד שיגדל שלה וייבם אותך, כי כן המנהג במתיבמת, כי היוצאת וחפצה להנשא לאיש זר לובשת בגדי אבל ימים מעט כפי המנהג, ומתנחמת ולובשת שנים ותכס בצעיף ותתעלף עד שתנשא לאיש:

ABIDE A WIDOW AT THY FATHER’s HOUSE. The meaning thereof is that “you should conduct yourself there as a widow until Shelah be grown up.”

He suggested to her: “Place yourself in mourning, put on mourning garments, do not anoint yourself with oil, as a woman girded with sack-cloth for the bridegroom of her youth, until Shelah be grown up and he will marry you.”

Such was the custom of a widow waiting to be married: she who desires to be married to a stranger wears mourning garments only for a short period as is the custom, and then feigning comfort ***arrays herself in scarlet***. And she covered herself with a veil, until she be married to a man.

Comment: Ah thanks, I mistook 'Ramban' for 'Rambam'! DX

Comment: @Tamir Evan

Thankyou for reminding me!